# How do you recover from invalid tags in an rss feed

Tags: c#, xml, rss

I am working on a RSS feed reader. Some feeds have invalid tags like <i> and <b> in them (invalid for RSS). I get an exception when I parse them.

To demo the error, I posted sample code. Here is some info:

**Exception message:** Unexpected node type Element. ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content.

**Exception:** System.Xml.XmlException.

**Raw XML** See the XML for this rss: [http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001](https://west.thomson.com/about/feeds/west_prfeed.xml).
See the page source. The issue is on line 56 (<a> tag in rss)

**Exception comments:** If you look at the raw RSS, there is an <a> tag in it. The rss parser does not like this so it throws an exception on it. The error is in line 34 (Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);)

### **Is there a nice to to either process HTML tags in Rss feeds or to ignore them?**

**Note:** I added Microsoft's code to extend  XmlTextReader class. It is a means of bypassing invalid date in rss. Ignore that. I added it to the code to fix an irrelevant bug from Microsoft.

Here is a sample code that **you can run to see the exception**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
namespace RssTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoRSS();
        }


        public static void DoRSS()
        {
            string url = "https://west.thomson.com/about/feeds/west_prfeed.xml";
            var r = new MyXmlReader(url);
            SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(r);
            Rss20FeedFormatter rssFormatter = feed.GetRss20Formatter();
            XmlTextWriter rssWriter = new XmlTextWriter("rss.xml", Encoding.UTF8);

            rssWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                rssFormatter.WriteTo(rssWriter);
                rssWriter.Close();

                foreach (var i in feed.Items)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(i.Summary.Text);
                }

        }
    }


        //from microsoft
    public class MyXmlReader : XmlTextReader
    {
        private bool readingDate = false;
        const string CustomUtcDateTimeFormat = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"; // Wed Oct 07 08:00:07 GMT 2009

        public MyXmlReader(Stream s) : base(s) { }

        public MyXmlReader(string inputUri) : base(inputUri) { }

        public override void ReadStartElement()
        {
            if (string.Equals(base.NamespaceURI, string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                (string.Equals(base.LocalName, "lastBuildDate", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                string.Equals(base.LocalName, "pubDate", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                readingDate = true;
            }
            base.ReadStartElement();
        }

        public override void ReadEndElement()
        {
            if (readingDate)
            {
                readingDate = false;
            }
            base.ReadEndElement();
        }

        public override string ReadString()
        {
            if (readingDate)
            {
                string dateString = base.ReadString();
                DateTime dt;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dt))
                    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, CustomUtcDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ReadString();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Filter it with xslt/by some other means, no?

Comment: @Alex, please explain that some more. I get an XML exception when there are invalid tags, so how can I use xslt?

Comment: you could try to open up the feed XML in HtmlAgilityPack, usually does a good job in "fixing" unclosed tags, use the fixed output - won't propose this as a solution but it's worth a shot, even if unlikely to succeed

Comment: Is it an XML parsing exception, or is it that the RSS reader throws an exception that the feed isn't valid structure?  If you are able to load the feed as an XML source, then you can transform the XML into something that the RSS reader will accept.  If it's not well-formed XML, then you would need to get the provider to fix their feed or try scrubbing the feed with tools that "fix" issues and help produce well-formed XML.

Comment: Can you post an example of this invalid XML? Also, post the exception you get when there are invalid tags.

Comment: In the example below, <a href...> is used as a tag in RSS (in the URL below, line 56 col 160). Google reader can recover from it. How can you recover in .NET?:

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwest.thomson.com%2Fabout%2Ffeeds%2Fwest_prfeed.xml

Comment: How are you reading this with .NET and what problem do you have? Is an exception thrown? Show the exception.

Comment: Please show which exception you get and which line throws the exception. Show exactly which XML causes this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution worth examining:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9faa101f-0a1a-465f-a41a-3e52dd9f7526/everything-rss--atom-f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't, really. If the data is not valid XML, then it's not valid XML and the feed owner needs to fix it. Those tags need to be escaped, or else placed inside of a CDATA section.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I notice that some rss readers like google reader and yahoo have works-around. Like for example, they work around <em> to make text italics (emphasis). I would like to know it can be done in C#.

Comment: In the example below, <a href...> is used as a tag in RSS (in the URL below, line 56 col 160). Google reader can recover from it. How can you recover in .NET?:

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwest.thomson.com%2Fabout%2Ffeeds%2Fwest_prfeed.xml

Comment: Ok, if this is the error, then my answer stands: there's an element which is meant to have only simple content, but it's got mixed content instead. That's wrong, and the provider needs to fix it. Other than that, you would need to implement your own XmlReader similar to the example you posted.

Comment: Do you have any ideas to share on how to implement what I need?

Comment: @user: you can't always fix what someone else has broken! Sometimes you have to make them fix their own bugs. I recommend that you send the link to this question to the people who create the feed and tell them to be professional and fix their bug. Feel free to ask them nicely.